# Where are vagrant plugins installed?

Tags: windows, plugins, vagrant

I'm curious to find where exactly vagrant plugins are installed.  I'm currently looking at a vagrant installation on Windows, and my example is the vagrant-timezone plugin.  My best guess was in the C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-1.8.1\plugins, but I'm not seeing "timezone" anywhere around there?

Comment: did you look for `vagrant-timezone` ? on mac os plugins are in `$USER_HOME/.vagrant.d/gems/gems`

Comment: Thank you, Frédéric.  I did eventually stumble upon that directory, and found a few others along the way.  I've doc'd them in my answer.

Comment: See as well [Change VAGRANT_HOME directory on windows](https://harvsworld.com/2014/change-vagrant_home-directory-windows/) and [`VAGRANT_HOME`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/other/environmental-variables#vagrant_home) in the manual.

Answer (score 6):

From some more research, it appears that information for plugins is spread across a few locations:

- `%USERPROFILE%\.vagrant.d\plugins.json`

  - lists all installed plugins
- `%USERPROFILE%\.vagrant.d\gems\gems\"plugin_name-version"`

  - Directory (not sure what all the files do, but this looks like the bulk of it)
- `%USERPROFILE%\.vagrant.d\gems\specifications\"plugin_name-version".gemspec`

For my use case, I was looking to manually extract and install a plugin, so these seemed to be all that I needed to account for.